# How to check if current timezone is (UTC+9:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo on other languages?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, timezone

I was able to compare it by:

```
if (TimeZoneInfo.Local.ToString().Contains("Tokyo"))
{
 //do something ...
}
```

but the problem is if i use a Japanese native OS for example, the return string uses japanese characters instead of "Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo". In my condition, i checked if the string contains a string "Tokyo" therefore, my code will not work on japanese OS.

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Just check if it contains either `Tokyo` or `東京`.

Comment: but what about for other languages like chinese, korean etc..

Comment: It may be good idea to add information on why you are doing it... Checking for particular timezone does not seem very useful...

Comment: its a checking that we use to know the current timezone being used by the server. different settings will be set dpending on their timezone.

Comment: Checking server's timezone seems like bad idea to me - there is generally not much correlation between server's timezone and anything else (i.e. servers could be configure to be in "UTC" timezone for having legacy logs to be created reasonably, or just always be in timezone of physical location of server, not the owner).

Comment: What we basically needed was to get the same timezone being set on the server's date and time settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to use the [`TimeZoneInfo.Id` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.timezoneinfo.id.aspx). I don't think it will be localized, because it has to match some registry keys.

> In Windows XP and Windows Vista, it corresponds to the subkeys of the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zone branch of the registry. It can be passed as a parameter to the FindSystemTimeZoneById method to retrieve a particular time zone from the registry.

If for some reason that doesn't work, perhaps the [`BaseUtcOffset` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.timezoneinfo.baseutcoffset.aspx) would be enough for you.

Comment: i used timezoneinfo.local.id. it worked for me.. Thanks very much